# How to remove trailing forward slash

Tags: text-processing, sed, files, string, search

For each line in my file, if the line ends with / I want to remove it. How to do this?
My attempt:

```
sed -e "s/$\/$//" myfile.txt > myfile_noslash.txt
```

Did not work.

Comment: The forward in forward slash is silent, and not written. “slash”.

Comment: Slasher!  :-)  xxxxxx

Comment: Which is also [called solidus in unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)) and stroke in British English, apparently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command simply has an errant dollar sign. Fixed:

```
sed -e 's/\/$//' myfile.txt > myfile_noslash.txt
```

Comment: Use another delimiter, then there is no need for backslash: `sed 's%/$%%'`

Comment: @rexkogitans True. But as OP also used the escaped slash, it makes it clearer where his mistake is. That's why I also used `-e`.

Comment: I believe that many people do not even know that the delimiter can be chosen freely, hence I mentioned it.

Answer (score 9):

Your command would try to delete a `$` followed by a `/` at the end of the lines in your file.

You don't need the initial `$` in the regular expression:

```
sed 's/\/$//' myfile.txt >myfile_noslash.txt
```

The substitution command `s` in `sed` can take almost any character as its delimiting character, for example

```
s@/$@@
```

or

```
s,/$,,
```

or

```
s|/$||
```

So your command could be

```
sed 's,/$,,' myfile.txt >myfile_noslash.txt
```

Comment: I find the underscores harder to read when they coalesce together: perhaps a hyphen or tilde would make a better delimiter? Hyphen has the advantage of not needing the shift key.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble True. I'm changing that one to commas instead.

Comment: @D.Ben Personally I like the pipe cause it's so easy to look at and see the different sections in the expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use any character as a delimiter in the regex

`sed -e 's%/$%%' myfile.txt > myfile_noslash.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below python and worked fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('l.txt','r')
for i in k:
    print re.sub("/$","",i).strip()
```

Comment: It's recommended to use `with open('l.txt') as k:` (which can also accept mode string). The `with open()` is a context manager, which will close the file properly without having to explicitly do so. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31334226/3701431 Otherwise, OK answer. Regex is not particularly necessary though - built in methods could handle it